# How to replace a CloudPage with a newer version of that CloudPage on the same URL?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Just an easy question: Is there a way to replace a CloudPage with a newer version of that CloudPage on the same URL and schedule this change?

The reason why I'm asking is because I want to prepare all the new landing pages and publish the new landing pages at the moment that the old landing pages are unpublished.

Hope you guys can help out.

Comment: Uhm you can just edit the existing ones and never publish them. That means you test the functionality on other sides and then copy the side and paste it into the old one and then click publish on a particular date for all the new pages.

Comment: The comment above you was the answer. Before it was a bug from MC and now it works like it should. The problem is that comments can't be marked as answers.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to use two CloudPages.

1. A "sandbox" or "staging" CloudPage where you can test changes and refine any details that you're not ready to set live yet. You can publish to an inconspicuous URL if you need to view it live.
2. A "production" version that is live.

Once the staging version of the CloudPage is ready, fully tested, and approved, you can copy and paste the updates to the production version and publish.